# Shortest distance from a point to a face of a polyhedron

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have a **convex** polyhedron. And I have a point **inside** this polyhedron. I'm trying to figure out an algorithm to find the distance to the closest face of this polyhedron. How can I do that?

I know that once I have the actual faces of the polyhedron, I can iterate over them and calculate this distance. This is not a problem. The problem is that I have only the vertices, say:

```
0 0 0
0 0 4
0 4 0
...
```

And from those vertices I need to get actual faces. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just compute the 3D hull?

Comment: that's right! thank you. If you write this as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compute the 3D hull in time O(n log n) and then, for each face, compute the distance from the point to the plane on which the face lies.

Comment: This works because the point is inside the convex polyhedron. If the point were outside, or if the polyhedron were not convex, then it is possible that the closest face would not have the closest plane.